# "InvalidArgumentException" Could not find a storyboard named "Details" in bundle NSBundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unit-testing

I have created a Cocoa Touch framework with unit test target. Now I am trying to build and run my unit test cases which has code to initiate storyboard. But it is not able to load storyboard files and throwing me the error.

```
"InvalidArgumentException" Could not find a storyboard named "Details" in bundle NSBundle </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Agents> (loaded).
```

Here is my code

```
UIStoryboard *sb =
  [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:"Details" bundle:nil];
```

It is working when I provide the bundleID explicitly like

```
UIStoryboard *sb =
[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:"Details" bundle:[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"com.abc.xyz"]];
```

So I am not sure why it is not taking the bundle implicitly. What configuration do I need to change. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I have mentioned there . its @"Details"

Comment: you have to set the story board name in info.plist file is "Details"????

Answer (score 1):

Add your `Details. storyboard` the file under "Copy Bundle Resources"

Go to Xcode project icon and navigate to: `Targets > Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources`

Click the `+` button at the bottom to add the storyboard file.

***OR***

Check for target membership in File Inspector for storyboard if is checked. Make sure you have that value checked.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried adding my storyboard file in my test target as I wanted it there, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (in my obj c may be mistakes):

```
UIStoryboard *sb =
  [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:"Details" bundle: Bundle(for: Self.self)]
```

In swift:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Details", bundle: Bundle(for: Self.self))
```

In fact you need to bundle storyboard to your framework